# How to take backup of sql server 2012 database from network computer

Tags: networking, sql-server-2012, database-backups

I'm using sql server 2012 and windows server 2008 R2 on my server machine.
And windows-7 and sql server 2012 on network computers.
I were made a user for sql server 2012 (server machine).
From that user i am able to connect with the database server from remote computer.
Now i need to take backup of any database from network computer using this user(Sql server authentication).

### Query for backup

> Backup database hwbss to disk = '\Dpc1\SqlBackup\hwbss.bak';

When i run this query on both machine server and client.It troughs error.

### Error message

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '\\ASHISHRATHOR-PC\SqlServerBackup\BSS100_Ashish_BSS.bak'.       
Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Can any one tell me how can i take backup of sql server 2012 database from network computer using sql server authentication.

Note:- I am able to take backup of database on network in sql server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by using Map Network drive. You have to create such drive to the remote folder that you want to store the backup. Then you have to give sql server permissions to see the network drive. Check in task manager which is the account the sql server is running on. You must grant write permission on this account to the network drive(usually it's Network Service).